# Electron project cannot import package that uses fs

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, fs

In our project we have nested packages, one of which uses fs to read files from the machine (B):

```
import fs from "fs";
```

Then we have another package (A), that imports this package (B). The application is being run on electron, and it uses React (we don't have any webpack configs). Although the electron works fine, it throws the following error when it's trying to call a method from the package B that uses fs.

```
TypeError: fs_1.default.existsSync is not a function
```

We have also tried to include the fs package with `const fs = require("fs")` and `const fs = window.require("fs")` in B with no success. I guess the main point would be to allow other packages (B-C-D-...) work normally even if the package A (that imports them) would be using electron.

Everything electron related that is imported to the package A is done using the following method:
`const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');`
This does not work on the other packages with fs. If the B package is tested without electron, it works correctly, so the issue arises somehow from the usage of Electron.

tsconfig.json moduleResolution is set to "node", and Electron window has the following settings:

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    contextIsolation: false,
  },
});
```

How should the application be able to use the fs package, even if it is imported by package built on Electron?

Comment: It sounds to me like maybe something that is meant to be happening in the render process is happening in the main process.

Comment: >  The application is being run on electron, and it uses React (we don't have any webpack configs)

Are you using create-react-app or something? That uses webpack under the hood.

Comment: @Erick yes, the app was done with create-react-app and electron was integrated to it. although react uses webpack to my knowledge its not possible to directly change it as the file exists only in react npm folders?

Comment: Yeah, create-react-app has its own Webpack configuration that you can't modify out of the box. You would need to eject or use a library like `craco` to rewire your config.